# How do I insert Popup Messages Randomly in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, popupwindow

Hi I am trying to bring up popup messages in random intervals using AsyncTask.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       boolean popped=false;
   @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
       new PopupTask().execute();
    }
```

This method will bring up a popup message only if there is no other popupmessage brought up.

```
  private class PopupTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    Random r=new Random();
    int i1=r.nextInt();
    if(popped==false){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
            = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
       final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                   popupView, 
                   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);  

                if(!popped){
                    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView, 90, 420);
                    popped=true;
                }

                 Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                 btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      popupWindow.dismiss();
                      popped=false;

                     }});
    }
    return null;
}
```

However i get an exception when control gets to the LayoutInflater statement.

Is there any better way of doing this? Thanks in advance

Edit:This is my stacktrace

```
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:329)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:988)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:897)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at com.example.popupsamp.MainActivity$PopupTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:85)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at com.example.popupsamp.MainActivity$PopupTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-25 02:40:33.298: E/AndroidRuntime(9724):     ... 5 more
```

Comment: To help with what you have, please provide the exact error message (stacktrace).

Answer (score 0):

You can not show a popup in a thread other that the UI thread. Move this code to the onPostExecute() method.

Answer (score 0):

Overide the `onProgressUpdate();`
and do something like this.

```
private class PopupTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
 @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

Random r=new Random();
int i1=r.nextInt();
if(popped==false){
   publishProgress(100); // Pass any Number
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
super.onProgressUpdate(values);
if (values[0] == 100) {

LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
        = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
   final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
               popupView, 
               LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  
                     LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 

    }
}
```

also read this tutorial for [asyncTask](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.com/p/android-asynctask-example.html)